# Getting setTimeout() to work with loading a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move an element in a page after the page loads. I'm trying to get the element to load, and then move after three seconds. Instead, the element just moves immediately on the page load. Here is my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  #container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #animate {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<body id="body">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="animate"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("animate");

    function myMove(element) {
      var posx = 0;
      var posy = 25;
      var opacity = 0;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 40);

      function frame() {
        if (posx == 10) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          posx++;
          opacity = opacity + .1
          element.style.top = posy + "%";
          element.style.left = posx + "%";
          element.style.opacity = opacity;
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("body").addEventListener("load", setTimeout(myMove(elem), 3000))
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: setTimeout returns an interval ID, so you basically just did.  `.addEventListener("load", 310);`  And you are executing the function so you did `myMove(elem); setTimeout(undefined);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
setTimeout(() => myMove(elem), 3000)
```

otherwise it sets a timeout for whatever `myMove(elem)` returns, which means `myMove(elem)` runs immediately

Comment: still needs more than that, setTimeout would execute right away

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need this:

```
// Run at DOM loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log('DOM is loaded');
  // Move
  setTimeout(function(){ myMove(elem); }, 3000)
});
```

OR

```
// Run at full page load
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
  // Move
  setTimeout(function(){ myMove(elem); }, 3000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `myMove` methods execute immediately. To avoid this you can use arrow functions supported in ES6 or move `myMove` to a function

using arrow function (supported in ES6):

```
document.getElementById('body').addEventListener(
  'load',
  setTimeout(() => myMove(elem), 3000),
);
```

Convert to function

```
document.getElementById('body').addEventListener(
  'load',
  setTimeout(function () {
    myMove(elem);
  }, 3000),
);
```